# HASHBYTES function

Tags: sql-server

The below script gives the following error message:

"Msg 8152, Level 16, State 10, Line 10
String or binary data would be truncated."

```
 select convert(varbinary(max),HASHBYTES('md2',(select [Secteur]
  ,[Hub]
  ,[Group]
  ,[Enterprise]
  ,[Manager]
  ,[BM]
   from [Hubs] for XML auto)))
```

I mention that the maximum length of input rows is 123 bytes.

Any ideas why this message? (I use SQL Server 2014) Many thanks

Comment: official documentation says,maximum return value is `varbinary (maximum 8000 bytes) `

Comment: Or more pertinently it also says "For SQL Server 2014 and earlier, allowed input values are limited to 8000 bytes."

Comment: You have neither an `ORDER BY` nor a `WHERE` in your query. That means you're converting the entire table to XML, with a row ordering that's not deterministic. That's probably not what you want as an input for a hash. If all you want is a mechanism to detect if the data has changed and you're not married to an MD2 hash over XML, consider using `CHECKSUM_AGG`.

Comment: Thanks  Jeroen Mostert!

Answer (score 1):

HASHBYTES is limited to 8000 character input in SQL 2014 and older.  It is not limited in SQL 2016+.   I suspect your query when converted to XML is more than 8000 bytes.

You can use the undocumented `fn_repl_hash_binary` to get an MD5 hash (but not an MD2) in sql 2014 for long input data, but I don't recommend it.  Not only is it undocumented, it does not work in Azure SQL at all.

I believe you will need to use a CLR function to calculate an MD2 of large binary data in SQL 2014.